# Use Bottle.py over a wireless network

Tags: python, ctypes, wireless, host, bottle

I want to use `bottle.py` over a wireless network. Unfortunately I do not know how to go about setting this up. The code I want to execute over a wireless network (Execute from another computer) is:

```
import ctypes
from bottle import get, post, request, run

@get('/control')
def message():
    return '''<form method='POST' action='/control'>
        <input name='message'   type='text'/>
        <input type='submit'/>
        </form>'''

@post('/control')
def send():
    Message  =request.forms.get('message')
    MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
    MessageBox(None,Message,'MESSAGE', 0)

run(host=127.0.0.1, port=8090)
```

Comment: I've adjusted the indentation to what would actually make sense. You are allowed to edit your own post and if you can improve it then I encourage you to do so.

Comment: It doesnt kill my eyes now, thanks James :)

Answer (score 1):

And to answer question - are you sure you want to bind it only @ 127? What I mean - 127.0... is localhost... try 0.0.0.0 or the IP